# Problem with connection to MySql from igrafx VBA. It works properly in EXCEL VBA

Tags: mysql

Problem with setting connection to MySql Database in Igrafx VBA.

It works properly in EXCEL VBA. Any suggestions?

```
Sub DBtest()

Dim conn As Object
    Dim serverName As String
    Dim dbName As String
    Dim userName As String
    Dim password As String
    
    serverName = "localhost"
    dbName = "ql"
    userName = "root"
    password = "q###d$$$$k"
    
    
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    
    ' Ustaw parametry połączenia
    conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.3 Unicode Driver};Server=" & serverName & ";Database=" & dbName & ";Uid=" & userName & ";Pwd=" & password
    
    ' Otwórz połączenie
    On Error Resume Next
    conn.Open
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Błąd połączenia: " & Err.Description
    Else
        MsgBox "Połączenie udane!"
        conn.Close
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Please be more specific about the 'problem'

Comment: Did you try to ping localhost from same host? Or maybe replace 'localhost' with 127.0.0.1 ? Another gess is to add port to comm object.

Comment: Vasin! Thank you for your help. I changed server to 127.0.0.1 but still has an error 

"[Microsoft][Menedżer sterowników ODBC] Nie można odnaleźć nazwy źródła danych, a nie ma podanego sterownika domyślnego"

"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The data source name cannot be found and there is no default driver specified"

This code works properly in Excel but it does not work in Igrafx VBA nor in the MS Word VBA. Lack of some libraries.
Thank you once again for your contribution

King regards
Tadeusz Lis

Comment: Maybe I should add something in Reference menu containing libraries references. Any idea how to isolate problem?